# Ruby algorithm syntax

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am learning algorithms. In one algorithm called "Decode string" that is:

Given an encoded string, return it's decoded string.

> The encoding rule is: k[encoded_string], where the encoded_string
>   inside the square brackets is being repeated exactly k times. Note
>   that k is guaranteed to be a positive integer.
>
> You may assume that the input string is always valid; No extra white
>   spaces, square brackets are well-formed, etc.
>
> Furthermore, you may assume that the original data does not contain
>   any digits and that digits are only for those repeat numbers, k. For
>   example, there won't be input like 3a or 2[4].
>
> Examples:
>
> s = "3[a]2[bc]", return "aaabcbc".
>
> s = "3[a2[c]]", return "accaccacc".
>
> s = "2[abc]3[cd]ef", return "abcabccdcdcdef".

The answer is

```
def decode_string(s)
  1 while s.gsub!(/(\d+)\[([a-z]*)\]/) { $2 * $1.to_i }
  s
end
```

The Regex is understandable but the "1 while" it's simply impossible for me to understand. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some really strange Ruby syntax going on here, it's far from idiomatic or conventional. Using `,` to separate two statements is something most code review tools will complain vigorously about ([Code Climate](https://www.codeclimate.com) and [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) being good examples of those), and `1 while` is right up there.

Presumably the intent here is to loop and repeat until that condition is complete. `while` operates in one of two modes, either as a classic flow control structure:

```
while cond
  # ...
end
```

Or as a trailing loop condition:

```
expr while cond
```

They're opting for the second case but since this mandates an expression, even a pointless one, they're stubbing in `1` to make it syntactically valid.

The whole idea here is to keep smashing that method until it stops making changes. Perhaps a better approach is:

```
loop do
  break unless s.gsub!(/(\d+)\[([a-z]*)\]/) { $2 * $1.to_i }
end
```

**Update**: If you're not looking for readability but minimal character counts for whatever reason, here's your solution:

```
def decode_string(s)
  1while s[/(\d+)\[([a-z]*)\]/]&&=$2*$1.to_i;s
end
```

I'd really steer away from this style of coding, this little nugget of code is really the opposite of self-explanatory, but it's functionally equivalent. `1while` makes even less sense than `1 while` but Ruby doesn't seem too bothered by it.

Comment: [Nah I like mine better :-P](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/57145/3-lines-python-2-lines-ruby-regular-expression)

Comment: @StefanPochmann The Rubyist me likes to keep things organized. The Perlist in me can see ways of shaving off a half dozen characters from that. Two different ways of solving problems.

Comment: Shave off half a dozen from mine you mean? I'd be interested in that... (unless you mean the spaces or actually doing it in Perl)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, white-spaces and such, no need for that! Perl Golf veteran and all that.

Comment: Has been a while since I last Perl-golfed...  I think in this case I followed the bbatsov Ruby style guide as far as I knew it back then, that's why the spaces. Occasionally I still golf, but most of the time I just try to be short while following reasonable style.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Added a more compact representation for academic purposes. Perl is more ideal for this with its minimal syntax, but Ruby is still lean if you pull out all the stops. Maybe trying to finish [Shenzen IO](http://www.zachtronics.com/shenzhen-io/) isn't time wasted at all!

Comment: Cool, thanks. Gonna digest that now. But I can already tell you that you don't need the space between `1` and `while` :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann My syntax highlighter gets upset, but you're right, that's "extraneous".

Comment: Very nice trick you used there, thanks again. I was only able to shrink the regex: `1while s[/(\d+)\[(\w*)]/]&&=$2*$1.to_i;s`. At this point I actually believe that back then I pretty much wasn't golfing at all and was just going for straightforwardness...

Comment: Had a look at Shenzen IO. No way. No. I actually coded in assembly for years. Never going back to that. No.

Comment: Upvoted for the Update part now. In the future I might btw use `loop while ...` instead of `1 while ...`. I think that's very cute and self-explanatory.

Comment: Your opinion, please, on the stylistic difference between `break unless...` and `break if s.gsub!(/(\d+)\[([a-z]*)\]/) { $2 * $1.to_i }.nil?`

Comment: Your explanation is awesome. Thank you @tadman. You said about rubocop and the horrible metrics about this method, can you help me to find a way that this algorithm would be metric and understandable?